# how do I truncate a string with javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

I'm using jRibbble to bring in a feed from Dribbble to my site. I'd very much like to truncate the descriptions to 2-lines. Is this possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function getDribbbleShots() {   
  $.jribbble.getShotsByPlayerId('abenjamin765', function (playerShots) {
      var html = [];

      $.each(playerShots.shots, function (i, shot) {
          html.push('<div class="col-md-4"><div class="thumbnail"><a href="' + shot.url + '" target="_blank">');
          html.push('<img class="shot-image" src="' + shot.image_url + '" ');
          html.push('alt="' + shot.title + '"></a><div class="caption"><h4>'+ shot.title +'</h4><p>'+shot.description+'</p></div></div></div>');
      });
      $('.dribbble-feed').html(html.join(''));
  }, {page: 1, per_page: 9});
});
</script>
```

http://abenjamin765.github.io/folio/

Comment: `.split('\n').slice(0,2)`?

Comment: where would I put that? I'm new-ish to javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can hide text past a certain point by limiting the height of your description in css, and setting your `text-overflow` behavior in css.

```
.ellipsis {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Note that this will only work for a single line description. If you want to extend your description to multiple lines, there are a few ways you can do that.

See: http://html5hub.com/ellipse-my-text/

Alternatively, if you don't care if the overflow is indicated with an ellipsis, you can simply set

```
.thumbnail .caption p {
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: where would I put that?

Comment: @AaronBenjamin You would put this in place of `shot.description` in your code.

Comment: Thanks Luke. I'm still not seeing it truncate :( http://abenjamin765.github.io/folio/

Comment: That's because your descriptions aren't multiple lines. What you're trying to achieve isn't "truncating a string," rather it is hiding text past a certain point. You can do this entirely in CSS.

Comment: I tried using jquerysmartellipsis, but still a no-go.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59213/discussion-between-luke-willis-and-aaron-benjamin).